# How to use Django and angular together?

Tags: django, angular, deployment, django-rest-framework

I've a django backend and angular frontend, on my local machine to use both together, I've to run both server's using `ng serve` and `python manage.py runserver` but now I'm planning to deploy it to heroku and I've no idea how will it work, also is there any official guide for using django and angular together.
P.S. - I'm using `django-rest-framework` for making api calls from frontend to backend.

Answer (score 0):

i never do it before but i think you can do it separately

deploy your django: [Heroku django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python)

then deploy your angular app [Heroku angular](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-deploy-your-angular-9-app-to-heroku-in-minutes-51d171c2f0d)

change your base url to heroku urls

i hope that it would help you :D